# Reading data from device connected to BLE dongle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am trying to read temperature sensor data from a device that is connected to a BLE dongle. The dongle uses port COM5, which I have accessed using this code:

```
s = serial('COM5','BaudRate',57600,'DataBits',8,'StopBits',1,'Parity','None');
fopen(s);
```

However, this device offers multiple services using GATT protocol. (ex. The data I would like to access has a characteristic ID 0x2a1c and a service ID 0x1809.) How would I write to the COM5 port that I would like to read the data using these IDs?

Comment: In most cases BLE dongles implement the controller part of the Bluetooth specification. You are missing the host. If this is the case, I don't think you will be able to achieve your goal by just writing to the serial port with Matlab. Can you give us more detail about the dongle you are using?

Comment: Yes I am using a BLE112 dongle from Bluegiga. It connects with an earpiece that acts as a temperature sensor, heart rate monitor, and other things.

Comment: So it seems you have host and controller on that dongle. From the Silicon Labs website: "The USB dongle has a virtual COM port that enables seamless host application development using a simple application programming interface. ". Get the documentation of that API and look for the command to read a GATT characteristic. Of course you have to discover your earpiece and connect first. Also look at this https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2015/08/06/_how-to_run_a_bgsc-FM28